# Spring kafka transaction id is wrong at start?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm using spring kafka 2.2.2.RELEASE

Our broker has strict authorization verification.

Here is our client configuration :

- spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix=test.
- topic : topic
- groupId: group

It should generate a transactional id : "test.group.topic0"

**Problem:**

When I start the application, KafkaMessageListenerContainer#onPartitionsAssigned is called and the transactional id used is "test0".
It seems like in this case, the kafkaTemplate is not considered to be in a listenerContainer.

This is leading to an Unauthorized exception because this transactional id is refused by the broker

**Question**

Is it normal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks; it's a bug; I [opened an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/900).